# Derby , XML data , length

Tags: java, xml, database, derby

I am trying to insert an xml object into a database . The type of the column is  XML.
When my XML has some 1100 lines, i get an exception saying that ,

```
" A string constant starting with ''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
' is too long."
```

Kindly, Suggest some possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the complete stack trace from your exception?

Some sample code that demonstrates the problem?

What is the actual length of your string constant?

The underlying length restriction on the XML data type is quite large: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rreflimitsxml.html

I suspect that you are encountering a problem that is unrelated to the XML data type itself, but rather is related to the specific technique you are using to manipulate the data in your program, such as one of the limits in http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefstringlimits.html

That is, you are probably not using XMLPARSE and/or XMLSERIALIZE effectively.

More details would certainly help.